# PHP : Compare and display if value equal

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to this, I can't compare the loop value came from database. In database I have 4 rows all of those are displaying in a table, and I have a value of array that contains 1, 2, 4. How do I compare this, so I can display checked attribute only for has a value of 1,2 ,4.

Database table

```
 roles    |    level
---------------------
  bod     |      1
 event    |      2
  htab    |      3
  tab     |      4
```

PHP code

```
  $array_soc = array = (1,2,4); //<-- This is the array that i need to compare
  $sql10 = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_event_roles");
    $count = 1;
    $counts = 0;
    $array_level = [];
    while($soc_sqll0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql10)){

        $output .= '<tr>';
        $output .= '<td>'.($soc_sqll0['level'] ==1 ? '
        <div style="float:left;">'.$soc_sqll0['roles'].'</div>
        <div style="float:right; font-size:15px; "><i> (Recommended to have) <i></div> ' : ''.$soc_sqll0['roles'].'').'</td>';
        $output .= '<td style="width:50px;">
        <input type="checkbox" value="'.$count.'"
        '.( $array_level[$counts] == $array_soc[$counts] ? 'checked' : '').' //<-- Here is the problem, i'm trying to compare but i got an error undefined offset 
        id="check_boxs'.$count.'" name="roles_checked_userStaff[]"></td>';
        $output .= '</tr>';


        array_push($array_level, $count);
        $count++;
        $counts++;

    }
```

So the output, is should something like this 
[image]

Comment: First of all, please stop using the `mysql_` functions immediately. They were deprecated in PHP 5.5, which is so old that it no longer even receives security updates, and completely removed in PHP7, which was released in December, 2015. Instead, use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

your `$array_level` is used before it has a value in your loop.
Either initialize `$array_level[0] = ...` or put your `array_push($array_level, $count);` before `$array_level[$counts] == $array_soc[$counts]`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on this piece of code, this error appears to be caused due to the array  `$array_soc`  is equal to `array = (1,2,4);`  and `$counts` is bigger than 2.

To use `$array_soc[$counts]`, `$counts` need to be between 0 and 2 (positions of array: `array = (1,2,4);`). Otherwise, the an error undefined offset will be emitted.